# Spark can't read CSV file and convert to Dataset

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

When I used Spark to read a CSV file and convert it to a Dataset, I got following error. I can't figure out the reason. My code is provided below. Also http://eforexcel.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/10000-Sales-Records.zip to download the CSV file.

I am using Scala: 2.12.3, Spark: 2.4.0.

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`itemType`' given input columns: [Order ID, Total Profit, Country, Total Revenue, Ship Date, Unit Cost, Sales Channel, Unit Price, Total Cost, Units Sold, Order Date, Order Priority, Region, Item Type];
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$checkAnalysis$1$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$checkAnalysis$1$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$2(TreeNode.scala:278)
...
...
```

Here is my code:

```
import spark.implicits._
case class Sales(region: String, 
              country: String, 
              itemType: String, 
              salesChannel: String, 
              orderPriority: String, 
              orderDate: String, 
              orderId: Long, 
              shipDate: String, 
              unitsSold: Integer, 
              unitsPrice: Double,
              unitCost: Double,
              totalRevenue: Double, 
              totalCost: Double, 
              totalProfit: Double
              )
 val ds = spark.read 
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.csv("src/main/resources/datasets/10000 Sales Records.csv")
.as[Sales]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got mismatch between csv header columns and the case class.
From the csv header, you need to massage the data to bring it to match with your case class. That is you need to remove the spaces, capitalize the second word. The below workaround will work for you.

Note that I changed the unitsPrice: Double,  to unitPrice in your case class.

```
val ds = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("in/10000_Sales_Records.csv")

ds.printSchema()
val sch1 = ds.columns.map( x=> x match { case a if a.contains(" ") => { val q=a.split(" ");q(0)+q(1).capitalize } case a => a.toLowerCase } )
val ds2 = ds.toDF(sch1:_*)
ds2.printSchema()

val ds3 = ds2.as[Sales]
ds3.show(false)
```

Results:

```
root
 |-- Region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sales Channel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Order Priority: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Order Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Order ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Ship Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Units Sold: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Unit Price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Unit Cost: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Revenue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Cost: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Profit: double (nullable = true)

root
 |-- region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ItemType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SalesChannel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OrderPriority: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OrderDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OrderID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ShipDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- UnitsSold: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- UnitPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- UnitCost: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalRevenue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalCost: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalProfit: double (nullable = true)

+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|region                           |country                         |ItemType       |SalesChannel|OrderPriority|OrderDate |OrderID  |ShipDate  |UnitsSold|UnitPrice|UnitCost|TotalRevenue|TotalCost |TotalProfit|
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|Sub-Saharan Africa               |Chad                            |Office Supplies|Online      |L            |1/27/2011 |292494523|2/12/2011 |4484     |651.21   |524.96  |2920025.64  |2353920.64|566105.0   |
|Europe                           |Latvia                          |Beverages      |Online      |C            |12/28/2015|361825549|1/23/2016 |1075     |47.45    |31.79   |51008.75    |34174.25  |16834.5    |
|Middle East and North Africa     |Pakistan                        |Vegetables     |Offline     |C            |1/13/2011 |141515767|2/1/2011  |6515     |154.06   |90.93   |1003700.9   |592408.95 |411291.95  |
|Sub-Saharan Africa               |Democratic Republic of the Congo|Household      |Online      |C            |9/11/2012 |500364005|10/6/2012 |7683     |668.27   |502.54  |5134318.41  |3861014.82|1273303.59 |
|Europe                           |Czech Republic                  |Beverages      |Online      |C            |10/27/2015|127481591|12/5/2015 |3491     |47.45    |31.79   |165647.95   |110978.89 |54669.06   |
|Sub-Saharan Africa               |South Africa                    |Beverages      |Offline     |H            |7/10/2012 |482292354|8/21/2012 |9880     |47.45    |31.79   |468806.0    |314085.2  |154720.8   |
|Asia                             |Laos                            |Vegetables     |Online      |L            |2/20/2011 |844532620|3/20/2011 |4825     |154.06   |90.93   |743339.5    |438737.25 |304602.25  |
|Asia                             |China                           |Baby Food      |Online      |C            |4/10/2017 |564251220|5/12/2017 |3330     |255.28   |159.42  |850082.4    |530868.6  |319213.8   |
|Sub-Saharan Africa               |Eritrea                         |Meat           |Online      |L            |11/21/2014|411809480|1/10/2015 |2431     |421.89   |364.69  |1025614.59  |886561.39 |139053.2   |
|Central America and the Caribbean|Haiti                           |Office Supplies|Online      |C            |7/4/2015  |327881228|7/20/2015 |6197     |651.21   |524.96  |4035548.37  |3253177.12|782371.25  |
|Sub-Saharan Africa               |Zambia                          |Cereal         |Offline     |M            |7/26/2016 |773452794|8/24/2016 |724      |205.7    |117.11  |148926.8    |84787.64  |64139.16   |
|Europe                           |Bosnia and Herzegovina          |Baby Food      |Offline     |M            |10/20/2012|479823005|11/15/2012|9145     |255.28   |159.42  |2334535.6   |1457895.9 |876639.7   |
|Europe                           |Germany                         |Office Supplies|Online      |C            |2/22/2015 |498603188|2/27/2015 |6618     |651.21   |524.96  |4309707.78  |3474185.28|835522.5   |
|Asia                             |India                           |Household      |Online      |C            |8/27/2016 |151717174|9/2/2016  |5338     |668.27   |502.54  |3567225.26  |2682558.52|884666.74  |
|Middle East and North Africa     |Algeria                         |Clothes        |Offline     |C            |6/21/2011 |181401288|7/21/2011 |9527     |109.28   |35.84   |1041110.56  |341447.68 |699662.88  |
|Australia and Oceania            |Palau                           |Snacks         |Offline     |L            |9/19/2013 |500204360|10/4/2013 |441      |152.58   |97.44   |67287.78    |42971.04  |24316.74   |
|Central America and the Caribbean|Cuba                            |Beverages      |Online      |H            |11/15/2015|640987718|11/30/2015|1365     |47.45    |31.79   |64769.25    |43393.35  |21375.9    |
|Europe                           |Vatican City                    |Beverages      |Online      |L            |4/6/2015  |206925189|4/27/2015 |2617     |47.45    |31.79   |124176.65   |83194.43  |40982.22   |
|Middle East and North Africa     |Lebanon                         |Personal Care  |Offline     |H            |4/12/2010 |221503102|5/19/2010 |6545     |81.73    |56.67   |534922.85   |370905.15 |164017.7   |
|Europe                           |Lithuania                       |Snacks         |Offline     |H            |9/26/2011 |878520286|10/2/2011 |2530     |152.58   |97.44   |386027.4    |246523.2  |139504.2   |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Can you explain `sch1:_*` in `val ds2 = ds.toDF(sch1:_*)`?  @stack0114106

Comment: it is a vararg assignment..sch1 contains the reformatted column names from the csv header and we are replacing it with this syntax.. this is very concise and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

may be in input file contains header - Region,Country,**Item Type**,Sales Channel,Order Priority,Order Date,Order ID,Ship Date,Units Sold,Unit Price,Unit Cost,Total Revenue,Total Cost,Total Profit

either edit header in input file or case class

Name : Item Type ( with space) where as in case class without space